Dart annotated-shelf + Swagger, in the easy way is it possible?
I spent some time searching for packages/solution but I failed miserably. The goal is straight forward:
I want to create class which works as REST API handler and handles POST, GET etc requests , and simple way to produce swagger doc available via http.
It was very straight forward in java or python, but I've no idea how to do it in Dart. Currently I got first part of my use case, covered by usage of annotated-shelf package. So my service class looks like:
@RestAPI(baseUrl: "/admin")
class AdminService {
  final MainRepository repository;

  AdminService({required this.repository});

  @PUT(url: "/community")
  Future<CommunityPayload> addNewCommunity(CommunityPayload community) async {
    final updated = await repository.addNewCommunity(community);
    return updated;
  }
}

In perfect world, I would like to add some swagger doc annotation (same way I use @PUT) and put description inside code. But I didn't found any package to do so.
What I would like end is something like:
@RestAPI(baseUrl: "/admin")
class AdminService {
  final MainRepository repository;

  AdminService({required this.repository});

  @PUT(url: "/community")
  @Swagger("This endpoint add new community to system")
  Future<CommunityPayload> addNewCommunity(CommunityPayload community) async {
    final updated = await repository.addNewCommunity(community);
    return updated;
  }
}

Is it possible to achieve in Dart?
